# How to update nuget version to latest

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I tried via extension and updates - update nuget package manager.
It starts creating vsix.exe something like this in process and it goes on creating it more than 1000 process.
Finally my ram space is occupied fully and system crashes.

[image]

Another way i try to uninstall that extension, again the same case like above happens.

I couldn't figure why.
Visual studio 2012 i am using.

Please help me to figure this out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is the reason for the problem.
But i granted my user account full admin privilege then that problem got solved.